# How to fallback to software rendering in Java3D?

Tags: opengl, windows-server-2008, direct3d, java-3d

We are having some weird problems using Java3D over a Windows' remote desktop. The remote machine is a virtualized server, which can't use the (physical) server's graphic card. When I run the app, the following error pops:

```
Unable to create DirectX D3D context.
Neither Hardware and Software Renderer are available.
Please update your video card drivers
and get the latest DirectX available at http://microsoft.com/directx
```

After switching to OpenGL (starting the JVM with `-Dj3d.rend=ogl`) the same error appears! What is possibly happening? How can I fallback to software rendering, either with OpenGL or DirectX, when the error appears?

**EDIT:** I've already tried using another OpenGL vendor, using Mesa3D's DLLs instead of the native ones, but it did nothing different. I also installed DirectX SDK and tried to start Java3D with the reference driver (`-Dj3d.d3ddevice=reference`), but it didn't work either.

Comment: Java3D 1.5.2 supports "j3d.rend" but it is no longer supported in Java3D 1.6.0 and later (using only JOGL 2 for hardware acceleration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error appears because if OpenGL fails, Java3D tries to use DirectX. If that fails, too, then the pop is shown.

I didn't manage to solve it because, instead of trying to change things at the remote server, I tried to emulate the problem at my own machine by disabling the video driver. I still don't know why both problems aren't equivalent, but after I returned to work on the server and put DirectX's `d3dref9.dll` at Java's `\bin`, it worked.

Now I have an entire new problem, as the JVM can't find the DLL if I place it at `java.library.path` or Tomcat's `\bin` :) Problems just can't not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
Under Windows:
    First, open the Display Properties pane by right clicking on desktop screen and choosing Properties item in menu. In that pane, display the Settings tab, and click on the Advanced button. Then in the Troubleshoot tab of the pane that opened, check the Hardware acceleration cursor is at its maximum on Full, confirm your choice and try to run your program again.

If the previous operation didn't resolve your problem, update the OpenGL and DirectX drivers of your graphic card with the latest available ones, and try to run Sweet Home 3D again.